# Webkit spacing behaviour - corrected by Web Inspector

Tags: html, css, webkit, spacing, web-inspector

I've encountered a random issue in Webkit based browsers (tested in Chrome and Safari).  On a website I maintain I've been updating the artwork we use for our error messages, and it looks great in all browsers except Webkit based browsers.  The problem I am having seems to disappear when I toggle any CSS rule on or off through the Web Inspector.

The problem:

[image: Webkit CSS Bug?]

The spacing above the text-size controls shouldn't be there, it should look like:

[image: Corrected]

The annoying thing is that the spacing disappears when I toggle **any** css property in Web Inspector.

The HTML for the popup is:

```
<div class="popup">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <a class="normalFont" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Normal Font"><span>Normal Font</span></a>
    <a class="largerFont" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Larger Font"><span>Larger Font</span></a>
    <a class="largestFont" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Largest Font"><span>Largest Font</span></a>
    <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Close"><span>Close</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="message">...</div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

And the key part of the CSS is:

```
.popup
{
  width: 310px;
}

.popup .header
{
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(...);
}

.popup .header .block
{
  float: left;
  height: 19px;
  width: 210px;
}
```

Where `.block` is applied to:

[image: CSS Block]

Does anyone know why this occurs and if there is a workaround?

**Update**: A live example (although using outdated graphics) is available [here](https://www.direct-travel.co.uk/Quotation/Select-Cover/bFV4ckF1UWdnRkNCS0NxeWVGV2dwczMydll0S0hzOEcxUktsQ3BhWHlLMEh6ODFwM2E1azFRPT01). Clicking an item such as 'Medical Expenses' in a Webkit browser displays the popup with spacing error.

Comment: A live example of some kind would help us a lot :)

Comment: I've added a link to a LIVE example, don't be confused by the imagery, it's using dated artwork.

Comment: Try creating the smallest possible code that has this bug and put it up on jsbin.com or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a float issue that seemed to allow absolutely position elements sitting above the floated elements to affect how the elements was flowing within the absolutely positioned elements.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but hopefully it's enough to point you in the right direction.

In `Client.Popups.js`, inside the `CreateOverlay` function, if I comment out this line:

```
ResizeOverlay(offset.top, offset.left, width, height, target == null ? null : target);
```

and replace it with some quick hacky code to make an overlay:

```
$("body").append('<div style="position:absolute;top:0;width:' + $(document).width() + 'px;height:' + $(document).height() + 'px;background:red;opacity:0.5"></div>');
```

The weird gap is gone.

So my suggestion is to look closely at/rewrite the overlay code.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the very late response. Thanks for looking at the code, turns out that I think I've either uncovered a bug in Webkit, or (assuming Webkit is correct), then a bug in all other rendering engines! The extra space is due not `clear`ing of the absolutely position element, which doesn't make sense, as it is no longer in the document flow. Adding a `clear` rule corrects the style.

Comment: No problem, this was a while ago, so I'd forgotten about it. The link in your original post still doesn't look right in Chrome. It's an old version or you haven't put the fix live yet?

Comment: Fix isn't going live until our next release, which won't be till the end of March. So glad it was figured out though!