# Strange margin bug in Chrome 9

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, margin, margins

I have run into a strange problem with Google Chrome 9: I have specified a left-margin for an input element but Chrome ignores it when I load the page.

However, when I open the Developer Tools and turn that specific declaration off and then on again, the margin is applied correctly.

The rule in question is:

```
margin: 8px 0 0 33%;
```

I thought it might have something to do with mixing units, but using:

```
margin: 1% 0 0 33%;
```

I have the same problem.

It is only Chrome where I have noticed the problem, IE9 and Firefox 3.6 apply the margin without any problems.

Is this a known problem and how can I get around it?

By the way, I´m using Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, I haven't tested any other versions / operating systems yet.

**Update:** I´m having exactly the same problem with Chrome 9 in Linux / Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: How odd. I see you have a couple of useless answers :) The issue happens for me with Chrome 9, but *not* with Chrome 11. Here's a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593420/webkit-spacing-behaviour-corrected-by-web-inspector/) I attempted to fix a while ago. Unfortunately, it contains no useful information to help you, I think.

Comment: @thirtydot Funny, I can indeed click on any other (unrelated...) style rule in the Developer Tools and it jumps directly to the right position...

Comment: Is it fixed now? Or has my Chrome 9 suddenly decided not to do it anymore?

Comment: @thirtydot I put the margin on the `li` instead. Problem solved. Now it´s just slightly off to the right, grrrrrrrr...

Comment: FWIW, I'm having the same problem right now in Chrome 23 mac. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I messed around with the css in firebug and found that this works:

```
margin-top:8px;
margin-left:33%;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed that but I´m still seeing the button on the left on page-load.

Comment: How are you loading the button? You could try putting it in a `<div>` with `margin-left:33%;`. And keep the `margin-top:8px;` on the button.

Comment: You could also try `margin-left:172px` on the button, so that you don't have to mix the units.

Comment: The button is in an unordered list so I have solved the problem giving the margin to the `li` instead of the button. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the floats, you can do that by adding overflow:hidden to the UL element that wraps the LI's.

```
#block_contact_form ul { overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added that but at page-load it still shows the button on the left.

Comment: Try adding the li to the selector #block_contact_form ul li { overflow:hidden }...it's strange, in Chrome if I add it the button instantly jumps.

Comment: @Seth it is doing that because you are adding it in the inspector and it is reapplying the style. This is not actually the fix, but the same thing as disabling and re-enabling the style.

Answer (score 1):

1. set `position:relative` for the parent element ( eg: `li` OR `span` )
2. set `float:left` ( for Left Direction ) Or `float:right` ( for Right Direction ) for this input `[type:button]`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a solution has been found but if a css solution for such a bug is not possible one could always try to set the css using JQuery or plain javascript.

```
$(.button input).css({margin: 8px 0 0 33%});
```

Comment: That doesn't work either, Stofke. I am now facing the same problem. For me, the only way to get around it is to remove overflow-x:hidden, declared in the same rule. Unfortunately I have no other elements I can put the rule on ...